# Export text from xml with self-closing tag

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, lxml, tei

I have a set of XML TEI files, containing transcriptions of document. I would like to parse these XML file and extract only text informations.

My XML looks like:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF8'?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <text>
    <body>
      <ab>
        <pb n="page1"/>
          <cb n="1"/>
            <lb xml:id="DD1" n="1"/>my sentence 1
            <lb xml:id="DD2" n="2"/>my sentence 2
            <lb xml:id="DD3" n="3"/>my sentence 3
          <cb n="2"/>
            <lb xml:id="DD1" n="1"/>my sentence 4
            <lb xml:id="DD2" n="2"/>my sentence 5
        <pb n="page2"/>
          <cb n="1"/>
            <lb xml:id="DD1" n="1"/>my sentence 1
            <lb xml:id="DD2" n="2"/>my sentence 2
          <cb n="2"/>
            <lb xml:id="DD1" n="1"/>my sentence 3
            <lb xml:id="DD1" n="2"/>my sentence 4
      </ab>
    </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

I have tried with LXML to access to the informations, by doing:

```py
with open(file,'r') as my_file:
    
    root = ET.parse(my_file, parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding = 'utf-8'))
    list_pages = root.findall('.//{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}pb')
    for page in list_pages:
        liste_text = page.findall('.//{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}lb')
    
    final_text = []
    
    for content in liste_text:
        final_text.append(content.text)
```

I would like to have at the end something like:

```
page1
my sentence 1
my sentence 2
my sentence 3
my sentence 4
my sentence 5
page2
my sentence 1
my sentence 2
my sentence 3
my sentence 4
```

If I succeed to access to lb objects, no textual informations are linked to them.
Could you please help me to extract these informations?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your xml may have a problem in that you have several `xml:id` attributes with identical attribute values. Well formed xml [requires the value to be unique within the XML document](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/).

Assuming that's fixed, it would be easier to do if you lxml instead of ElementTree, because of lxml's better xpath support:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse(my_file)
for p in root.xpath('//*[name()="pb"]'):
    print(p.xpath('./@n')[0].strip())
    for lb in p.xpath('.//following-sibling::*[not(name()="cb")]'):
        if lb.xpath('name()') == "pb":
            break
        else:
            print(lb.tail.strip())
```

The output should be your expected output.